# Which is the better option to use: localStorage(), window.localStorage(), or document.localStorage()?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

The question says it all. I realize that all options *do* work in up-to-date browsers, but what is the semantically best choice, and why?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

According to W3C standards, the correct is `window.localStorage` because the `localStorage` attribute is part of window object. And it is not a function, it is an attribute.

Source: http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#dom-localstorage

Example: http://www.rajdeepd.com/articles/chrome/localstrg/LocalStorageSample.htm

Comment: As far as I can tell the localStorage object is not available off of the document object only the window.  So, one is not better than the other (document), only one is valid (window).

Comment: Actually, as 木川 炎星 said, it works (it is "valid"), but works just to avoid weak errors.