# Parsing JSON giving "unexpected token o" error

Tags: javascript, json

I am having a problem parsing simple JSON strings. I have checked them on [JSONLint](http://www.JSONLint.com) and it shows that they are valid. But when I try to parse them using either `JSON.parse` or the jQuery alternative it gives me the error `unexpected token o`:

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var cur_ques_details ={"ques_id":15,"ques_title":"jlkjlkjlkjljl"};
      var ques_list = JSON.parse(cur_ques_details);

      document.write(ques_list['ques_title']);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note: I'm encoding my strings using `json_encode()` in PHP.

Comment: Changed it to: var ques_list = JSON.stringify( cur_ques_details); Thanks.

Answer (score 811, accepted):

Your data is already an object. No need to parse it. The javascript interpreter has already parsed it for you.

```
var cur_ques_details ={"ques_id":15,"ques_title":"jlkjlkjlkjljl"};
document.write(cur_ques_details['ques_title']);
```

Comment: how to detect from jquery if data is already a valid json object?

Comment: @mko: In this case, you don't. You know it is or you don't. Look at it and see if it conforms to the JSON specification.

Comment: @DarkFalcon i went with if (typeof data == 'object') {                     dostuff } to check if it is an json object or just a plain string

Comment: Note that JSON is JavaScript Object Notation, so litteral JSON in javascript source is just a JS Object. We borrowed Javascript's object syntax for data transfer between programming languages because it was simple to use.

Comment: @FilipHaglund: Except the syntax for JSON is a lot more strict than the syntax for a JS object. For example, JS allows unquoted property names and JSON does not.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. I've been searching for this all evening!

Answer (score 72):

Try parse so:

```
var yourval = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: This worked for me for debugging. Thanks a lot. I realized I was echoing out extra unnecessary info from my controller.

Comment: Why use `jQuery`?

Comment: Why not use `JSON.parse`?

Answer (score 14):

Using `JSON.stringify(data);`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: ...
    success:function(data){
        JSON.stringify(data); //to string
        alert(data.you_value); //to view you pop up
    }
});
```

Comment: Just calling `JSON.stringify` will do nothing with your data, the function actually returns your _now_ serialized data.

Answer (score 11):

The source of your error, however, is that you need to place the full JSON string in quotes. The following will fix your sample:

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var cur_ques_details ='{"ques_id":"15","ques_title":"jlkjlkjlkjljl"}';
            var ques_list = JSON.parse(cur_ques_details);
            document.write(ques_list['ques_title']);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

As the other respondents have mentioned, the object  is already parsed into a JS object so you don't need to parse it. To demonstrate how to accomplish the same thing without parsing, you can do the following:

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var cur_ques_details ={"ques_id":"15","ques_title":"jlkjlkjlkjljl"};
            document.write(cur_ques_details.ques_title);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 10):

`cur_ques_details` is already a JS object, you don't need to parse it

Comment: There's no such thing as a "JSON object". JSON is a string. What you mean is a "JS object".

Comment: I think what he meant is "Javascript object"

Answer (score 6):

Response is already parsed, you don't need to parse it again. if you parse it again it will give you "`unexpected token o`". if you need to get it as string, you could use `JSON.stringify()`

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem when I submitted data using jQuery AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
   url:...
   success:function(data){
      //server response's data is JSON
      //I use jQuery's parseJSON method 
      $.parseJSON(data);//it's ERROR
   }
});
```

If the response is JSON, and you use this method, the data you get is a JavaScript object, but if you use `dataType:"text"`, data is a JSON string. Then the use of `$.parseJSON` is okay.

Answer (score 1):

I was seeing this `unexpected token o` error because my (incomplete) code had run previously (live reload!) and set the particular keyed local storage value to `[object Object]` instead of `{}`. It wasn't until I changed keys, that things started working as expected. Alternatively, you can follow [these instructions to delete the incorrectly set localStorage value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10710029/687274).

Comment: I had the same issue of `[object Object]`, my problem was that i was not storing the normal object rather i was storing DOM object. So, i got it done by extracting the useful values from the DOM object and storing them in an object, after that i converted that object to JSON. And then for getting the value i parsed that JSON object.