# "Unexpected token o" in JSON

Tags: java, android

I have an android app where I'm trying to send data from editText to server. I'm trying to pack data to JSON:

```
editTextLogin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextLogin);
editTextPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPass);
JSONObject logPass = new JSONObject();
try {
    logPass.put("login", editTextLogin.getText().toString());
    logPass.put("pass", editTextPass.getText().toString());
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
mSocket.emit("logPass", logPass);
```

After that I receive these data on server and try to parse it to JS object:

```
socket.on('logPass', function(dataJSON) {
    console.log(dataJSON.admin);
    data = JSON.parse(dataJSON);
});
```

I can print dataJSON, it is: `( login: 'admin', pass: '1234' )` but when I'm trying to parse it I have error:
`Unexpected token o`

What's it and how to solve it?

Comment: You mean: `{ "login": "admin", "pass": "1234" }`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON giving "unexpected token o" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617164/parsing-json-giving-unexpected-token-o-error)

Comment: I bet the string your passing is `"[object Object]"`

Comment: @Shaishav no, login: 'admin'

Comment: @JaromandaX Ok, and how to solve it?

Comment: I don't understand. You are accessing `dataJSON.admin` but are trying to parse `dataJSON` as JSON? You can only pass a **string** to `JSON.parse`. If accessing `dataJSON.admin` is successful then clearly `dataJSON` is not a string containing JSON.

Comment: @levshkatov - don't try to parse something unless it is a valid JSON string - a javascript **Object** is not a **String**

Comment: copy your JSON and check it on jsonlint.com then it will verify ok then only parse

Comment: I understand that it isn't a valid JSON. I'm asking how to make it valid in java code. What's wrong im my java code, why it creates a wrong JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

class JsonDemo {

   public static void main(String[] args){
      JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

      obj.put("login", "admin");
      obj.put("pass", "admin123");

      System.out.print(obj);
   }
}
```

OR

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

class JsonDemo {

   public static void main(String[] args){

      JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

      obj.put("login","admin");
      obj.put("pass","admin123");

      StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
      obj.writeJSONString(out);

      String jsonText = out.toString();
      System.out.print(jsonText);
   }
}
```

OUTPUT

```
{"login": "admin", "pass":"admin123"}
```

Bug Issue

```
mSocket.emit("logPass", logPass.toString());
```

I hae tried this is working..

Comment: Ok, but how to do the same with editText.getText() ?

Comment: I also try simle printing values in "" like you and it works, but I need to put values from editText

Comment: @levshkatov Escape the values with `\"` for `String` representation

Comment: mSocket.emit("logPass", logPass.toString()); try this it may work

Comment: @Shaishav What do you mean? I use simple admin 1234, it doesn't have `\"`

Comment: @Console.log Thanks! It helps!

Comment: @levshkatov gd keep it up and first always try to debug the issue