# Unexpected token < in JSON at position 2 jquery Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have an AJAX request with jQuery "autocomplete", like code bellow:

```
    var clientesList = [];

    $("#clientes").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, callback) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../../../Cliente/GetClientesByName",
                data: "{'nome':'" + request.term + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    debugger;
                    callback($.map(data.cities, function (obj) {
                        return obj.Main
                    }))
                }
            })
        }
    })
```

When the event is triggered, the error is showed in jquery.min??

> "Create:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position
>   2"

My input HTML is this:

```
<input type="text" id="clientes" class="form-control col-md-10" />
```

Comment: Your remote service could be returning HTML and not JSON. Also, your `data` is not valid JSON. Try `data: JSON.stringify({nome: request.term})`. The two could be related (bad data -> HTML error response)

Comment: Extending @Phil's comment, only quotes are valid string delimiters in JSON, not apostrophes. JSON may look like Javascript, but it's not.

Comment: I'd wager your request is being redirected because you're logged out, an error handler has kicked in, or a 404, and the `<` comes from the fact that you're actually being served a HTML document.

Answer (score 5):

My guess is that due to your malformed JSON `data` property, your server-side resource is returning an HTML error, hence the unexpected `<` character in the response.

Fix your data by creating a valid JSON string...

```
data: JSON.stringify({nome: request.term}),
```

This will produce a value like

```
{"nome":"whatever you typed"}
```

which is valid instead of

```
{'nome':'whatever you typed'}
```

which is not due to the single-quotes and possibly worse depending on the value of `request.term`.

Answer (score 2):

Try to stringify the response data and parse it again, take a look:

```
(...)
success: function (data) {
    // ----------------------------------------------
    // My suggestion
    // ----------------------------------------------
    // Re-rendering the JSON -> Stringify > Parse
    data = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data));
    // Debugging the JSON object in console
    console.log(data); 
    // ----------------------------------------------

    debugger;
    callback($.map(data.cities, function (obj) {
        return obj.Main
    }))
}
(...)
```

You can see more about in a relative issue like: [Parsing JSON giving "unexpected token o" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617164/parsing-json-giving-unexpected-token-o-error)

Answer (score 2):

valid json string must have double quote.

```
JSON.parse({"u1":1000,"u2":1100})       // will be ok
```

no quote cause error

```
JSON.parse({u1:1000,u2:1100})    
// error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 2
```

single quote cause error

```
JSON.parse({'u1':1000,'u2':1100})    
// error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 2
```

You must valid json string at https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/