# Convert string to json object inside ajax post

Tags: javascript

I have the following:

```
SignUp.prototype.submitForm = function() {
    let that = this;

    $(document).on('click', this.buttonSubmitSelector, function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        let current = $(this).closest('form'),
            data = current.serialize();

            console.log(JSON.parse(data));

        // if(that.isEmailValid(emailVal)) {
        //  that.removeError(emailInput);

        //  $.ajax({
        //      type: "POST",
        //      url: current.attr('action'),
        //      data: data,
        //      success: function(){
        //          that.displaySuccess(current);
        //          that.resetForm(current);
        //      }
        //  });
        // }
        // else {
        //  that.showError(emailInput);
        // }

    });
}
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
VM26559:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (signUp.js:60)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.js:5206)
    at HTMLDocument.elemData.handle (jquery.js:5014)
```

DATA is "form_build_id=form-wKUSwxF8He0krHpGo4N_vzyT9CuUD2HCWNF0dp3tpvk&form_id=sign_up_alert_form&nid=12&title=Production%20Training%20Scheme&email=as-web%40hotmail.com"

I have never come across this error before. How can it be fixed?

Comment: please console.log(data) and show the result

Comment: duplicated question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617164/parsing-json-giving-unexpected-token-o-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

serialize() does not output JSON format...
If you are using jQuery:

```
data = JSON.stringify(current.serializeArray());
```

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> data = current.serialize();
> console.log(JSON.parse(data));
> ```

The serialize method converts the data in a form to a URL Encoded string.

It does not convert it to JSON so you can't parse it with a JSON parser.

You can decode it with the [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) API (which is new and shiny and may require a [polyfill](https://github.com/WebReflection/url-search-params) to work in your browser).

```
data = current.serialize();
var searchParams = new URLSearchParams(data);
for (let p of searchParams) {
    console.log(p);
}
```