# How to parse JSON objects with identifiers into typescript?

Tags: json, typescript

I have a large json object that looks like this:

```
{
     "item1": {
         "key1": "val1",
         "key2": "val2",
         "key3": [
             "val4",
             "val5",
         ]
    },
    {
     "item2": {
         "key1": "val1",
         "key2": "val2",
         "key3": [
             "val3",
             "val4",
         ]
    }

    ... etc ...
}
```

I created an interface:

```
interface MyObj {
    key1: string;
    key2: string;
    key3: string[];
}
```

Then try to parse the json:

```
const myObj[]: {string: Myobj[]} = JSON.parse(response);
```

But I get the error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`. I have checked `response` in a json validator and it passes.

I want to parse `response` into an array of `MyObj`.

Comment: Is that normal there is missing commas in your JSON ?

Comment: Oops, I missed them out. Will edit the question.

Comment: `key3` is not an object, it's array right? how you are getting data in key-value pair inside array?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617164/parsing-json-giving-unexpected-token-o-error

Comment: typescript can't cause runtime errors - your `response` is not a well formed JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Few things going wrong here, your type definition here isn't using correct TypeScript syntax

```
const myObj[]: {string: Myobj[]} = JSON.parse(response);
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
             This looks weird
```

Also your response object is malformed, `key3` is invalid (halfway between an array and object).

Anyway, try defining the type for the response first, and then parsing:

```
type MyObj = {
  key1: string
  // etc ...
}

type Response = {
  [key: string]: MyObj
}

const data:Response = JSON.parse(response)
```

Comment: Ah, I typed out the array incorrectly. I have fixed it now. I tried your suggestion but still getting the same error.

Comment: My suggestion is incomplete, so I'm not sure what you've tried or what your error is ...

Comment: Btw your error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1` has nothing to do with TypeScript, it sounds like your actual JSON file is malformed.

Comment: The json is fine. It was static json so I just wrote a python script to format it as a TypeScript array of objects.