# How to clear localStorage? (JavaScript/jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I'm currently testing on my local machine so the URL is as following when the user presses `Sign out`

```
// The ********** is my site name, which i don't want releasing yet
http://localhost:8080/**********/logout/
```

Local storage item:

```
Key: tkn Value: EE8D9DA0F1D71A0BE8B80F3BA80343555655871151tk16
```

the following tests i've tried:

```
if (localStorage.getItem('tkn')) {
    localStorage.clear();
} 

if (localStorage.getItem('tkn')) {
    localStorage.removeItem('tkn');
} 

// I've also ran these both tests in the console of the browser 
// and they return back 'undefined' but the item is cleared.
```

However when I `sign out`, the user session is removed completely fine. However the localStorage doesn't seem to be cleared.

Could someone shred some light on this for me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete a localStorage item when the browser window/tab is closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943220/how-to-delete-a-localstorage-item-when-the-browser-window-tab-is-closed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of checking a specific property, check the `length`

```
if (localStorage.length > 0 ) {
    localStorage.clear();
}
```

localStorage is an implementation of [Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage) interface and Storage has a [property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage#Properties) called length

> **Storage.length**
>
> Returns an integer representing the number of data items stored in the
>   Storage object.

Comment: @charlietfl In that case, specific items should be checked. But here OP has specifically asked *how to clear localstorage*