# clear or remove local storage when close the tab or browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to clear or remove my local storage when close the tab or browser not in refresh (f5)
I have used localstorage.clear();. but this is clear cookies on f5. I only want when tab or browser close.

Comment: Use sessionStorage instead, it will be cleared automatically.

Comment: In session storage, cookies will clear in f5 also. but I only need closing the tab.

Comment: Web storage and cookies are different. How can it be "clear also" ?

Comment: I want to clear local storage.I am using multi color theme. I want to clear selected theme, when browser close means default theme reflect when browser open.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete a localStorage item when the browser window/tab is closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943220/how-to-delete-a-localstorage-item-when-the-browser-window-tab-is-closed)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the syntax of jquery or JS, but you can try this:

```
//when browser closed - psedocode
$(window).unload(function(){
 localStorage.removeItem(key);
 // more keys here
});
```

Here, "key" is the keys of all the values which you are storing in local storage. Other than that you can use "delete localStorage.key"  as well but I never used it so I can not explain in deep.