# Which function or event trigger when we clear browser history - Can I delete localStorage of particular tab only?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-chrome

Actually  I working on a project which need a situation, in which after deleting browser history, then it should only clear local storage of current opened tab, it should keep as it is other tabs local storage data

Comment: Are you developing a Chrome extension? A web page can't control what happens when the user deletes their browser history.

Comment: @Josh Lee thanks, I am developing angular application is there any way?

Comment: If the user chooses to delete their browser history, there is absolutely nothing the web developer can do about that.

Answer (score 0):

Just like the answers to [How to delete a localStorage item when the browser window/tab is closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943220/how-to-delete-a-localstorage-item-when-the-browser-window-tab-is-closed/34265782)

All you need to do:

```js
localStorage.removeItem(key);
```

Remove the specific key which you want to remove for that particular tab.

Or you will clear the whole localStorage using

```js
localStorage.clear();
```

Comment: Thanks@BooToo, but I want to clear local Storage only after cntl+shift+delete - > Clear History or through history -> Clear History, is it possible?

Comment: That is only possible when you are on the webpage ie the website you are developing so that you will listen to keypress event which in turn will clear your localStorage . Look at a [fiddled](https://jsfiddle.net/LLbygsmf/3/) example of your request. I hope it helps you.