# How to clear pesisted redux state to local storage on closing browser?

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, redux-persist

I am persisting the redux state to local storage in my react app so that i can use the persisted state across all tabs. But i could no where find how to clear it when browser closes. Currently the state present in local storage of browser is staying until i manually clear it. Even i tried using session storage but it is not available across browser tabs. Is their any option that i can clear the persisted store on closing the browser.

Comment: Have you tried something like that localStorage.clear() ?

Comment: *Even i tried using session storage but it is not available across browsers* - no, it is, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage#Browser_compatibility . You have XY problem. You're trying to do a weird thing that shouldn't generally be done. If you have problems with sessionStorage, consider addressing them directly.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20325763/browser-sessionstorage-share-between-tabs . localStorage can act as temporary storage. At this point I don't see problems if persists. As any cache, it can be invalidated with timestamps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete a localStorage item when the browser window/tab is closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943220/how-to-delete-a-localstorage-item-when-the-browser-window-tab-is-closed)