# Clear localStorage only on browser closed and not on tab

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage

Is there a way where we can clear the localStorage item only on browser closed and not on tab closed.I have been reading many articles and I couldn't find any relevant solution, so thought of asking here.

My requirement is I need to retain the data on localStorage item on tab closed, but need to clear the data on browser closed.

Below code works on both tab and browser closed.

```
window.onunload = () => {}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.localStorage.removeItem('keyName');
```

## Reference

[How to delete a localStorage item when the browser window/tab is closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943220/how-to-delete-a-localstorage-item-when-the-browser-window-tab-is-closed)

Comment: I am not sure if you actually need to use SessionStorage or not

Comment: this wont help, as it is simply removing the key.Please double check my question. My ask is simple. Clear the localStorage only on browser closed and not on tab closed.@wayne2