# How to remove a local storage item after closing browser?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to remove a particular item in the local storage after I quit the whole browser(not just the tab). I have searched google and I only got the answer for removing when (tab) closes and not whole application (the browser), any suggestions?

Comment: In this case why not use session storage then. session storage is destroyed when someone leaves the session

Comment: can I do it in react?

Comment: yeah you can do it in any javascript framework

Comment: literally operates in an identical way to local storage

Comment: so it automatically deletes it after browser closes or I have to pass in a particular option?

Comment: automatically deletes it

Comment: thats the essence of session storage. it only is available during a user's particular session

Comment: do the following sessionStorage.setItem('test', 'hello') and close your browser once it is set in session storage

Comment: but it also deletes it after I close a tab, I want it to be deleted only when the whole browser closes

Comment: if that's the case why are you using local storage then...

Comment: what should I use then?

Comment: if you absolutely must use it.... here's something that might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943220/how-to-delete-a-localstorage-item-when-the-browser-window-tab-is-closed

Comment: I don't necessarily need to use it I just want the item to be deleted after the browser closes and not after the tab closes

Comment: it's somewhat difficult to detect a tab closing or a browser closing in javascript i think the stack over flow i sent might point you in a decent direction

Comment: you are right, thanks for your help