# How to remove one value from a key in localstorage that has many values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, local-storage

I've seen this question asked before but the solutions didn't help me hence why i've asked it again.

Currently, I am storing values into an array and that array is getting stored into localstorage.

This is the object

```
data.items -

0: {id: 190217270, node_id: 'MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnkxOTAyMTcyNzA=', name: '3-Bit-CNC-Starter-Pack'}
1: {id: 187179414, node_id: 'MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnkxODcxNzk0MTQ=', name: 'inb-go}
```

I have mapped through this and used 'name' as the value. I am calling this value through a button using this function

```
const favs = [];

  function checkId(e) {
    if (e.target.value !== ""){
      if (!favs.includes(e.target.value)){
      favs.push(e.target.value);
      localStorage.setItem("name", JSON.stringify(favs));
      console.log(favs);
      document.getElementById("favsarray").innerHTML = favs;
      }
    }
     
    }
```

and to remove the value from localstorage I am using this function.

```
function removeId(e, value) {
    if (e.target.value !== "") {
     
      favs.pop(e.target.value);
      console.log(favs);
      document.getElementById("favsarray").innerHTML = favs;
      const stored = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("name"));
      delete stored[value, e.target.value];
      localStorage.setItem("name", JSON.stringify(stored));
      console.log(stored);
      
    }
  }
```

Although the value is being removed from the array, it is not being removed from localstorage.

side note - I am calling this function with a separate button.

console log

```
array (item is gone)
[]

localstorage (the value is still there)
[
    "Spiral-Up-Cut-Router-Bit"
]
```

But if I select another item to be added to localstorage, then the previous item gets removed.

```
UNFAVORITE - FUNCTION REMOVEid
[
        "Spiral-Up-Cut-Router-Bit"
    ]

 NEW FAVORITE - FUNCTION NEWId

[
    "graphqless"
]
```

I hope this makes sense, I tried to add detail to it as best as possible.

Comment: delete is not used on arrays

Comment: do you have a solution because removeitem removes the whole key.

Comment: splice() the array instead or create new array with filter()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [localStorage.removeItem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/removeItem) method to remove item from storage:

```
function removeId(e, value) {
   if (e.target.value !== "") {     
      favs.pop();
      // other code here

      localStorage.removeItem('name'); // method to remove item from storage
      
   }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

If an item is removed from array and we want to set this updated value to localstorage, then we can just update this value:

```
function removeId(e, value) {
   if (e.target.value !== "") {     
      favs.pop();
      console.log(favs);
      document.getElementById("favsarray").innerHTML = favs;
      const stored = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("name"));
      delete stored[value, e.target.value]; // this code looks very fishy - charlietfl

      localStorage.setItem("name", JSON.stringify(favs));

      console.log(stored);      
   }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, that deletes everything because it has the same key. That's the issue i keep running into.

Comment: @shar27 please, see my updated reply

Comment: `pop()` doesn't take any arguments. Using `delete` here looks really fishy

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you. Can't believe it was just one piece,

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to just overwrite the item in localStorage. Once you remove the item from the `favs` array, call `localStorage.setItem("name", JSON.stringify(favs));` again and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this will help you but anyway I am sharing.

I don't understand this part of the abovementioned code:

```
delete stored[value, e.target.value];
```

What are you passing in the **value and e.target.value**? If it is the name ("Spiral-Up-Cut-Router-Bit") itself then the delete won't remove the value from the array. Usually, when you use the **delete** operator on the JS array you need to pass the index of the value, not the value itself.

Also, When you delete an array element, the array length is not affected. This holds even if you delete the last element of the array.

When the delete operator removes an array element, that element is no longer in the array.

[image: Delete operation on array]

You can refer to the above output image, when I deleted the array values using the value even though its output is true it does not delete the value from the array. But when I used the index value for the delete, it deleted the value from the array.

*Note: The array just removed the value but did not clear the index.*

Maybe, you should use splice to remove specific values from the array and store the new array into the storage.

Also, the delete operator works well with JS objects. If you want to read more about this you can go to this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete).✌

Delete using splice:

`var trees = ['redwood', 'bay', 'cedar', 'oak', 'maple']; trees.splice(3,1); console.log(trees);`

Comment: that was helpful, thank you

Answer (score -1):

As suggested, use `splice` (which will also update the Array's `length`) to delete the entry from the Array.

```js
const stored = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("name"));
const index = stored.indexOf(nameValue);
if (index !== -1) {
  stored.splice(index, 1);
  localStorage.setItem("name", JSON.stringify(stored));
}
```

See:

[image]