# I want to remove item from local storage key with the function

Tags: javascript

```js
function remove(current) {

    let text = "Are You Sure ?";


    if (confirm(text) == true) {
        current.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
        // document.getElementById("tablebody1").deleteRow(element.parentNode.rowIndex);
        text33 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("storex"))

        function rem(arr, index) {
            return arr.filter(function(ele) {
                return ele != index
            })
        }

        localStorage.setItem('text32', JSON.stringify(result));
        localStorage.getItem("text32")
    }
}
```

I am trying to delete the items from my localstorage I render the table data on the screen but my table data is coming into the localstorage i want to delete particular item  for example:

if i have localstorage just like that

```json
0: {namex: "ANUJ", lnamex: "ANUJ", emailx: "anuj123@gmail.com"}
1: {namex: "ANUJ", lnamex: "ANUJ", emailx: "anuj123@gmail.com"}
2: {namex: "ANUJ", lnamex: "ANUJ", emailx: "anuj123@gmail.com"}
3: {namex: "ANUJ", lnamex: "ANUJ", emailx: "anuj123@gmail.com"}
4: {namex: "ANUJ", lnamex: "ANUJ", emailx: "anuj123@gmail.com"}
5: {namex: "ANUJ", lnamex: "ANUJ", emailx: "anuj123@gmail.com"}
6: {namex: "rohit", lnamex: "ANUJ", emailx: "anuj123@gmail.com"}
```

let say I want to delete 6 items. How can i do so or if i delete it when I refresh the page it come again

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete a localStorage item when the browser window/tab is closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943220/how-to-delete-a-localstorage-item-when-the-browser-window-tab-is-closed)

Answer (score 2):

You can remove `localstorage` item with this method:

```js
//setting item
localStorage.setItem('image', 'myCat.png');

//removing item
localStorage.removeItem('image');
```

Comment: sir, this will delete  all the items in the key i want to delete the items by index number.

Comment: you have to change your `localStore` design for that case or you have to use more complex storages like `indexedDb` (for storing values like JSON) or use `Web SQL`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function example(){

  let array = [
    {namex: "1", lnamex: "ANUJ", emailx: "anuj123@gmail.com"}, 
    {namex: "2", lnamex: "ANUJ", emailx: "anuj123@gmail.com"},
    {namex: "3", lnamex: "ANUJ", emailx: "anuj123@gmail.com"},
    {namex: "4", lnamex: "ANUJ", emailx: "anuj123@gmail.com"},
    {namex: "5", lnamex: "ANUJ", emailx: "anuj123@gmail.com"},
    {namex: "6", lnamex: "ANUJ", emailx: "anuj123@gmail.com"}
  ];
  
        localStorage.setItem('text32', JSON.stringify(array));
        
        let getDataFromLocalStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("text32")); //convert your saved string array to object
        
        let result = getDataFromLocalStorage.filter((x, idx) => idx != 1);

        document.getElementById('ex').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result)
}
```

You have to save your array as a string in local Storage so you have to get it back and convert it to Object and use **filter()** method. it will give all the data except 1th index object according to above example

**if you want to remove 6th one you have to send the index number as 5 because array objects are start form 0th index**

then save it back to local storage as a string if you want

[here is the JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Janaka_Ravindra/n4zrybjc/)